# Static files not loading in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to create a homepage for my app but my page keeps loading after adding the `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIR`. it gives Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 49634) in my terminal. This is my home.html

This is my settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

this is my urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Unclear what you mean by `but my page keeps loading` and what "gives Broken pipe". And you forgot to add home.html contents

Answer (score 0):

```py
   # -------- handle Static Files In dajngo --------
   
   # Steps:
       # 1 - Create (static) folder in Root Directory of Project
       # 2 - Paste Your Static Files Folder in (static) Folder (js,css,images...etc)
       # 3 - Now Do Setting in (setting.py)
              STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   
       STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]

           #-------- OR ----------

       STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']


       # 4 - add {% load static %} tag on top of html page
       # 5 - Now use ({% static 'assets/image.jpg' %}) tag in HTML File for calling static files
       # 6 - Done
```